# Stark effect in Polonium and Plutonium

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I found the following question given as an exercise in one lecture notes:

> What are differences between Stark effect in Polonium and Plutonium ? What are differences between Stark effect in light and heavy atoms ?

My idea is the following : different $Z$-numbers give us different energy levels and using the same field we can ionize one of this atom and the other is still non-ionized. Moreover for large $Z$ there is more degenerate states.

The second question : What kind of Stark effect we can observe in such situations (i.e. is it linear or quadratic) ?